# Why does this List comprehension take too long to evaluate on Erlang/OTP 20?

Tags: erlang

To find any 5 numbers whose sum = 100. This can be done in a loop but i was illustrating list comprehension to a friend only to realize this takes more than 30 mins on my Mac Book Pro,core i7, 2.2GHz

`[[A,B,C,D,E] || A <- lists:seq(1,100),B <- lists:seq(1,100),C <- lists:seq(1,100),D <- lists:seq(1,100),E <- lists:seq(1,100),(A + B + C + D + E) == 100]`

And if the question is changed to have the 5 numbers consecutive, the constructed list comprehension even takes much longer. If i am to solve this problem using a list comprehension, am i doing it right ? if yes, why does it take too long ? please provide a solution that may be faster, perhaps using a loop.

Answer (score 6):

The multiple generators behave like nested loops over the lists, and each call to lists:seq() will be fully evaluated each time. This takes a very long time, and spends most of that time allocating list cells and garbage collecting them again. But since they all evaluate to the same constant list anyway, you can rewrite it as L = lists:seq(1,100), [[A,B,C,D,E] || A <- L,B <- L,C <- L,D <- L,E <- L,(A + B + C + D + E) == 100]. Also, running this in the shell will be a lot slower than in a compiled module. On my macbook, the compiled code finished in about 2 min 30 s. And that's just using a single core. Compiling with [native] makes it run in 60 seconds flat.

Comment: I think It is best answer for our question, +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

Because it "creates" all the elements of a 100^5 list of list of 5 elements before it makes the filter, that represents 50000000000 elements.

**[edit]**
I reviewed the answer from RichardC and Alexey Romanov and I decided to make some tests:

```
-module (testlc).

-export ([test/1]).

test(N) ->
    F1 = fun() -> [{W,X,Y,Z}|| W <- lists:seq(1,N),X <- lists:seq(1,N),Y <- lists:seq(1,N),Z <- lists:seq(1,N), W+X+Y+Z == N] end,
    F2 = fun() ->L = lists:seq(1,N),  [{W,X,Y,Z}|| W <- L,X <- L,Y <- L,Z <- L, W+X+Y+Z == N] end,
    F3 = fun() -> [{W,X,Y,Z}|| W <- lists:seq(1,N-3), X <- lists:seq(1,N-2-W),Y <- lists:seq(1,N-1-W-X),Z <- lists:seq(1,N-W-X-Y), W+X+Y+Z == N] end,
    F4 = fun() -> [{W,X,Y,N-W-X-Y}|| W <- lists:seq(1,N-3),X <- lists:seq(1,N-2-W),Y <- lists:seq(1,N-1-W-X)] end,
    F5 = fun() -> L = lists:seq(1,N), [{W,X,Y,N-W-X-Y}|| W <- L, 
                                                         XM <- [N-2-W],      X <- L, X =< XM, 
                                                         YM <- [N-1-W-X],    Y <- L, Y =< YM] end,
    {T1,L1} = timer:tc(F1),
    {T2,L2} = timer:tc(F2),
    {T3,L3} = timer:tc(F3),
    {T4,L4} = timer:tc(F4),
    {T5,L5} = timer:tc(F5),
    _L = lists:sort(L1),
    _L = lists:sort(L2),
    _L = lists:sort(L3),
    _L = lists:sort(L4),
    _L = lists:sort(L5),
    {test_for,N,{t1,T1},{t2,T2},{t3,T3},{t4,T4},{t5,T5}}.
```

and the result:

```
1> c(testlc).      
{ok,testlc}
2> testlc:test(50).
{test_for,50,
          {t1,452999},
          {t2,92999},
          {t3,32000},
          {t4,0},
          {t5,0}}
3> testlc:test(100).
{test_for,100,
          {t1,4124992},
          {t2,1452997},
          {t3,203000},
          {t4,16000},
          {t5,15000}}
4> testlc:test(150).
{test_for,150,
          {t1,20312959},
          {t2,7483985},
          {t3,890998},
          {t4,93000},
          {t5,110000}}
5> testlc:test(200).
{test_for,200,
          {t1,63874875},
          {t2,24952951},
          {t3,2921995},
          {t4,218999},
          {t5,265000}}
```

Preparing the list outside of the list comprehension has a big impact, but it is more efficient to limit drastically the number of useless intermediate lists generated before the filter works. So it is a balance to evaluate. In this example, the 2 enhancements can be used together (Thanks to Alexey) but it does not make a big difference.

Comment: With a caveat that the intermediate list itself isn't actually created (I believe).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov It does create all the lists, but not a single list of all elements; see my answer.

Comment: I know that, it is why I have written "creates". My purpose is to warn about the fact that, although the syntax is pretty concise, it generates in background all the loops you describe. So use multiple generators with caution, in non critical processes. For fun, it is also possible to reduce the execution time by reducing the number of combinations: `[[A,B,C,D,100-A-B-C-D] || A <- lists:seq(1,96), B <- lists:seq(A,96), C <- lists:seq(B,96), D <- lists:seq(C,96)]` produces the list of all possible **ordered** list of 5 element which sum is 100; it takes 37s in the shell (PCwin7, intel I7)

Comment: Too fast before sleeping, a good version is `[[A,B,C,D,E] || A <- lists:seq(1,96), B <- lists:seq(A,96), C <- lists:seq(B,96), D <- lists:seq(C,96),(E=100-A-B-C-D)>0]`, and it should be possible to reduce it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Erlang strong when we use concurrence in programming, so you can also spawn 100 process to handle list of [1,...,100]. It can be easy for your laptop calculate. For example:

```
do()->    
    L100 = lists:seq(1,100),
    [spawn(?MODULE, func, [self(), [A], L100, L100, L100, L100]) || 
        A <- L100],    
    loop(100, []).
loop(0, Acc) -> Acc;
loop(N, Acc) ->
    receive
        {ok, Result} ->
            loop(N - 1, Acc ++ Result)
    end.

func(Pid, LA, LB, LC, LD, LE) ->
    Result = [[A,B,C,D,E] ||
             A <- LA,B <- LB,C <- LC,D <- LD,E <- LE,(A + B + C + D + E) == 100],
    Pid ! {ok, Result}.
```

With solution above, my laptop with i3 2.1GHz can be easy calculate in 1 minute. You can also spawn more process for shorter calculate. Process in Erlang is light-weight process so It can be easy start then easy stop.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be

```
[[A,B,C,D,100-A-B-C-D] || A <- lists:seq(1,100), B <- lists:seq(1,100-A), C <- lists:seq(1,100-A-B), D <- lists:seq(1,100-A-B-C), 100-A-B-C-D > 0]
```

Just not enumerating all possible `E`s when at most one will succeed should be 100 times faster (or more since there's less garbage produced). Also decreasing the sizes of lists for `B`, `C`, and `D` will improve even more.

But there is some code duplication there. Unfortunately, Erlang doesn't allow "local" variables in list comprehensions, but you can emulate them with one-element generators:

```
[[A,B,C,D,E] || A <- lists:seq(1,100), 
    BMax <- [100-A], B <- lists:seq(1,BMax), 
    CMax <- [BMax-B], C <- lists:seq(1,CMax), 
    DMax <- [CMax-C], D <- lists:seq(1,DMax), 
    E <- [100-A-B-C-D], E > 0]
```

Or to avoid repeated `lists:seq` calls, as @RichardC points out:

```
L = lists:seq(1, 100),
[[A,B,C,D,E] || A <- L, 
    BMax <- [100-A], B <- L, B =< BMax,
    CMax <- [BMax-B], C <- L, C =< CMax,
    DMax <- [CMax-C], D <- L, D =< DMax, 
    E <- [100-A-B-C-D], E > 0]
```